# MySql : wait_timeout & "mysql server has gone away" error message

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I've a page which selects data from a table based on the primary key of the table

```
ex: SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id=primary_key_value
```

As soon as I execute this from my CI page, I'm getting following error message

```
"Mysql server has gone away"
```

I searched in mysql reference manual, they are telling, its the cause of "wait_timeout" in configuration file. My configuration file has following settings

```
wait_timeout            = 10
```

Could someone help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MySQL Server Has Gone Away - MySQL 5.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html)

[link](https://drupal.org/node/259580)

[Another one](http://www.webbykat.com/comment/488)